# CSS Animate Div Width from Left to Right

Tags: css, animation

I'm trying to animate the width of two overlapping divs, in order to show / hide the text contained within them. I'd like one div to animate from left to right, and the other to animate from right to left, so that as one piece of text is being wiped away, the other is being revealed following it.

Here's a JS fiddle of what I've got so far, but they are both being revealed from left to right. How do I get 'cancel' to be revealed from right to left?

https://jsfiddle.net/a43wrq20/

I thought that these rules would do it, but it isn't working for me:

```
.foo {
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
}

.foo.active{
    right: 0;
    width: 120px;
}
```

Also, they both shift slightly as they're animating? Can anyone see an easy fix for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animate an element's width from right to left cause some issue in this case, as the animated elements child, `cancel-text`, is left aligned. It will look like it slides in from the right.

The simplest solution is to leave the `cancel-text`, and animate the login, give it a background color (so it hides the cancel), give them both an absolute position, and you'll most likely get the desired result (if I got it right)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.clicker').on("click", function(){
    // if($('.email.input').val() ){
      $('.email.input').toggleClass('up');
      $('.password.input').toggleClass('up');
      $('.signup').toggleClass('up');
      $('.login').toggleClass('up');
      $('.login-text-container').toggleClass('active');
    // }
  });
});
```

```css
.center-clicker {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  top: 5vh;
  position: absolute;
}

.clicker {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 7.5vh;
  background: none;
}

.clicker:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.text-container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 120px;
}

.login-text {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Ultra-Light", "Helvetica Neue Ultra Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  color: black;
}

.cancel-text {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Ultra-Light", "Helvetica Neue Ultra Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 2.6em;
  color: black;
}

.login-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.login-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s;
  transition: width .4s;
}

.login-text-container.active {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: width .4s;
  transition: width .4s;
}

.cancel-container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.cancel-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="center-clicker">
  <div class="clicker">
    <div class="text-container">
      <div class="cancel-container">
        <div class="cancel-text-container">
          <span class="cancel-text">cancel</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login-container">
        <div class="login-text-container active">
          <span class="login-text">&nbsp;log in&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just modified the `right:0;` value for the `.cancel-text-container` to `right:-110px;`, and the `left:0;` value for the `.login-text-container.active` to `left:10px;`

Is this what you want?:

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7oc9osf7/3/)

Comment: Thabks Luka, it's not quite what I'm looking for though - sorry if my description was good. I'd like to keep 'log in' and 'cancel' stationary, but have the width of their containing divs change to 'cover' and 'uncover' them. Not for 'cancel' to slide in, as with your example. I'd like 'cancel to do the opposite of what 'log in' does right now. Hope that makes sense!